# How to check rar install or not in linux via Bash Script?

Tags: bash, rar

How to check rar unrar installed or not in Linux via Bash Script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspiration get from Michael Krelin - hacker's post and python's and-or expression, you can just type this:

```
type -P rar > /dev/null && echo "rar is installed." || echo "rar is not installed."
type -P unrar > /dev/null && echo "unrar is installed." || echo "unrar is not installed."
```

Comment: It is unfair to attribute the idiom older than certain species of dinosauria to python.

Comment: ;-)))))) No, I'm not that old.

Comment: Should I put you after python?hmms

Comment: You can safely omit me, though, of course, if I indeed inspired  you it's up to you. Just don't put me *into* python.

Answer (score 2):

If you can try

```
type -P unrar >/dev/null && echo it\'s installed\!
```

That will, of course, only detect in `$PATH`, not anywhere on the system.

Comment: "!" should be stripped away from the code, or one alternative: type -P unrar > /dev/null && echo -e "unrar is installed\041"

Comment: @arnkore. you're right. I thought quotes would guard against it. (fixed)

Comment: it's my first time to see an echo without quotes, looks weird.-_-

Comment: It's syntax highlighting that makes it weird ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

missing() {
    echo $1 is missing 1>&2
    return 127
}

RAR=`type -P rar ||  echo missing rar`
UNRAR=`type -P unrar|| echo missing unrar`
```

Use $RAR or $UNRAR in your script... to do whatever. if they are missing then the script will echo that the command is missing

The `return 127` makes sure that if you use a condition statement, it will fail in case of missing files.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution :

```
$whereis rar
```